# Trigger update or delete mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I made a trigger:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER update_table2 after UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  //here goes an update action
END |
delimiter ;
```

Now i want that this trigger goes also : `after DELETE ON table1`

I tried like this:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER update_table2 after UPDATE or DELETE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  //here goes an update action
END |
delimiter ;
```

But this is not working. I know that I can create a specific trigger but for legibility, I want to use this way.
Hope mySql support this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create two triggers: (the `OR` clause is for T-SQL and others)

But to avoid future maintenance problems you can call to an stored procedure from both triggers:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER update_table2 after UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  //here goes an update action
  call sp_trigger_table1([params]);
END |
delimiter ;


delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER update_table2 after DELETE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  //here goes an DELETE action
  call sp_trigger_table1([params]);
END |
delimiter ;
```